# display nonsignificant coefficients with ggplot2 and legend display

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to show different colors for coefficients that are not significant (p>0.05) and the ones that are. Plus, if someone has a way to show the legend or signify the colors that would also be nice..

Any ideas?

Sample code:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)
library(dotwhisker)
library(MASS)

flights <- nycflights13::flights
flights<- sample_n (flights, 500)

m1<- glm(formula = arr_delay ~ dep_time + origin+ air_time+ distance , data = flights)
#m1<- glm(formula = arr_delay ~ . , data = flights)

m1<- stepAIC(m1)
  p<- dotwhisker::dwplot(m1)
  z<- p + 
    geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype="dashed")+
    geom_segment(aes(x=conf.low,y=term,xend=conf.high,
                     yend=term,col=p.value<0.05)) + 
    geom_point(aes(x=estimate,y=term,col=p.value<0.05)) +
  xlab("standardized coefficient") + 
  ylab("coefficient") +
  ggtitle("coefficients in the model and significance")
  print(z)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code already *kind of* does what you want. The problem is that the object `p` produced by `dwplot` already has a `geom_segment` layer and a `geom_point` layer with a number of aesthetic mappings. Their colors are currently mapped to the variable `model`, which is just a factor level allowing for different colorings when comparing models side by side. It is possible to over-write them though:

```r
p$layers[[1]]$mapping[5] <- aes(color = p.value < 0.05)
p$layers[[2]]$mapping[4] <- aes(color = p.value < 0.05)
```

And you can change the legend label with

```r
p$labels$colour <- "Significant"
```

By default, `dwplot` also hides the legend, but we can reset that with:

```r
p$theme <- list()
```

So without adding any new geoms or creating the object `z`, we have:

```r
p
```

[image]

Note that `p` is still a valid and internally consistent ggplot, so you can continue to style it as desired, for example:

```r
p + theme_bw() + geom_vline(xintercept = 0, lty = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi went back to this chart to implement this. Is it possible to change the legend to significant and nonsignificant?